# How to mash together cmd line and file data in curl?

Tags: curl

I have tons of JSON data ready to be posted to a DB via CURL. But the DB requires the start and end of the JSON to be formatted a certain way. In order to not tweak the huge dataset of files by going into each one and prepending and appending lines ... I would like to simply specify the additional beginning and ending text on the command line around the file. I do not consider editing the files via script to be a kosher solution, it feels wrong to mess with such a pristine stream of data directly.

Instead, I found the following mashup to be a decent way to accomplish this:

```
curl -d "prepend_string`cat filename.json`append_string" \
-X POST http://localhost:5984/database/_bulk_docs \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

But this has its limitations because in the above scenario, all the data is being brought into the command line from the file and then posted. As the real files are quite large, anyone would run into errors like:

```
-bash: /opt/local/bin/curl: Argument list too long
```

***So, for CURL, is it somehow possible to mash together the cmd line and file data such that they get posted successfully (by curl) like so in three separate pieces?***

```
#(this is make believe syntax)
-d "prepend_string" + @filename.json + "append_string"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `-d @filename` to read from a single file:

```
curl www.example.com -d @mypostdata.txt
```

Or use the standard input:

```
echo "Beginning"$(cat mypostdata.txt)"End" | curl www.example.com -d -
```

Or use a named pipe...